# Does intersystems cache have a wildcard to search global node?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

Sometimes i want to search a character with wildcard, I don't want to search all the global nodes to find specific characters. so i want to know is any wildcard i can use to match specific characters on global nodes.  as if i want to find `^G("abc")` in `^G` with `^G("*s*")`

Comment: see also this answer see also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370452/get-globals-similar-to-global-search-mask-intersystems-cache?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this using low level $order/$query functions as @
kazamatzuri correctly said, but you can use %Library.Global:Get class query - first parameter is namespace, and second parameter is pattern string. You can have a documentation on pattern syntax in the class itself or here https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GGBL_managing#GGBL_managing_view

Here is an example using CALL statement - let's assume we want to find all global nodes in ^%SYS global of USER namespace starting with "D":

```
DEV>d $system.SQL.Shell()
SQL Command Line Shell
----------------------------------------------------

The command prefix is currently set to: <<nothing>>.
Enter <command>, 'q' to quit, '?' for help.
[SQL]DEV>>call %Library.Global_Get('USER','^%SYS("D":"E"')          
1.  call %Library.Global_Get('USER','^%SYS("D":"E"')



Dumping result #1
Name    Value   Name Format Value Format    Permissions
^%SYS("DBRefByName","CONFIG-ANALYTICS") ^^f:\trakcare\config\db\analytics\  1
^%SYS("DBRefByName","CONFIG-APPSYS")    ^^f:\trakcare\config\db\appsys\ 1   1
^%SYS("DBRefByName","CONFIG-AUDIT0")    ^^f:\trakcare\config\db\audit0\ 1   1
^%SYS("DBRefByName","CONFIG-AUDIT1")    ^^f:\trakcare\config\db\audit1\ 1   1
^%SYS("DBRefByName","CONFIG-AUDIT2")    ^^f:\trakcare\config\db\audit2\ 1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

You'll have to implement that yourself using $ORDER or $QUERY. There are pattern matching and regex utils though.

Cheers!